# create variable to hold time created

Tags: c++, time

Im creating a contact list program and need to beable to record when the contact was created and list the contacts according to their creation date.

what can i use to give a variable a date? i know the time.h file has something inside, but i dont know how to use it with less code as possible.

perhaps

```
time.h seconds = timeStamp;
```

?

if this is the way, then what would the output be? and whats the best way to output it in order? this variable will be part of a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you can use  [`time_t`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time) for dates. If you need higher precision, use `clock_t`

You can get the current time as follows. Note that what is stored is an integer value of the number of seconds since January 1st, 1970.

```
#include <time.h>
....
time_t s = time(NULL);
```

See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/) for further details. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <time.h>
...
time_t seconds = time(NULL);
```

The `seconds` variable will contain the number of seconds since 1970, which is enough information to store both date and time.

You can use the `asctime` function to convert this value into a human-readable string.